Calculate divergence $\nabla \cdot \mathbf{F}$ in spherical coordinates
I hope someone can clarify something for me. I'm looking at this problem:
Calculate the integral
$$
I = \int_{V} (\nabla \cdot \mathbf{F}) \ dv
$$
where $\mathbf{F} = x \hat{\mathbf{x}} + y \hat{\mathbf{y}} + z \hat{\mathbf{z}}$ and the volume $v$ is a sphere with radius $R$ placed at the origin. I want to calculate this directly (not using divergence theorem).
My teacher solved this and said:
By using the definition of divergence in Cartesian and spherical coordinates, we find $\nabla \cdot \mathbf{F} = 3$. An infinitesimal volume in spherical coordinates is $dv = r^2 \sin \theta \, dr \, d\theta \, d\varphi$. So we get
$$
\int_{V} (\nabla \cdot \mathbf{F}) \, dv = \int_{0}^{R} \int_{0}^{2\pi} \int_{0}^{\pi} 3r^2 \sin \theta \, dr \, d\theta \, d\varphi = 3 \int_{0}^{R} r^2 \, dr \int_{0}^{\pi} \sin \theta \, d\theta \int_{0}^{2\pi} d\varphi = 4 \pi R^3
$$
I understand everything, except this: How do we get $\nabla \cdot \mathbf{F} = 3$ in spherical coordinates? For cartesian coordinates it's very easy:
$$
\nabla \cdot \mathbf{F} = \frac{\partial x}{\partial x} + \frac{\partial y}{\partial y} + \frac{\partial z}{\partial z} = 1 + 1 + 1 = 3
$$
But I don't understand how we get 3 by using spherical coordinates.
I'm using the correct formula I'm pretty sure of, so I can't see what I'm missing:
$$
\begin{align*}
\nabla \cdot \mathbf{F} &= \frac{1}{r^2} \frac{\partial \left( r^3 \sin \theta \cos \varphi \right)}{\partial r} + \frac{1}{r \sin \theta} \frac{\partial \left( r \sin^2 \theta \sin \varphi \right)}{\partial \theta} + \frac{1}{r \sin \theta} \frac{\partial \left( r \cos \theta \right)}{\partial \varphi}
\end{align*}
$$
$$
\begin{align*}
&= \frac{1}{r^2} \cdot 3r^2 \sin \theta \cos \varphi + \frac{1}{r \sin \theta} \cdot 2r \sin \theta \cos \theta \sin \varphi + \frac{1}{r \sin \theta} \cdot 0
\end{align*}
$$
$$
\begin{align*}
&= 3 \sin \theta \cos \varphi + 2 \cos \theta \sin \varphi
\end{align*}
$$
This does not equal 3.
I used
$$
x = r \cos \theta \sin \varphi, \quad y = r \sin \theta \sin \varphi, \quad z = r \cos \theta
$$

Your vector is the position vector. So there can't be any angular terms. Also this question belongs on Math.SE.

You're using the cartesian components of $\mathbf{F}$, but you need to write it in spherical coordinates as $\mathbf{F} = r \hat{\mathbf{r}}$.


This question is off topic on a physics site. 2. $F_r =r$ $\Rightarrow$ $div \mathbf{F}=\frac{1}{r^2} \partial( r^2 F_r)/{\partial r} = \ldots$.


Even if you wanted to do it this way, you also need to change the unit vectors themselves into spherical coordinates. Here you've somehow assumed all the r dependence in the x coordinate when clearly both y and z also depend on r...as they also depend on $\theta$ and $\varphi$.

Thank you guys, I now see.

The conversion between the Cartesian and polar basis vectors is
$$\tag1
\begin{pmatrix}\hat{\boldsymbol{r}}\\\hat{\boldsymbol{\theta}}\\\hat{\boldsymbol{\phi}}\end{pmatrix}=
\begin{pmatrix}
\sin\theta\cos\phi&\sin\theta\sin\phi&\cos\theta\\
\cos\theta\cos\phi&\cos\theta\sin\phi&-\sin\theta\\
-\sin\phi &\cos\phi & 0
 \end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}\hat{\boldsymbol{x}}\\\hat{\boldsymbol{y}}\\\hat{\boldsymbol{z}}\end{pmatrix}\,.
$$
A vector field $\boldsymbol{F}$ can be expressed in both bases as
$$\tag2
\boldsymbol{F}=F_x\,\hat{\boldsymbol{x}}+F_y\,\hat{\boldsymbol{y}}+F_z\,\hat{\boldsymbol{z}}=F_r\,\hat{\boldsymbol{r}}+F_\theta\,\hat{\boldsymbol{\theta}}+F_\phi\,\hat{\boldsymbol{\phi}}\,.
$$
The invariance of $\boldsymbol{F}$ under the coordinate transformation  means that the components of $\boldsymbol{F}$ are related as
$$\tag3
\pmatrix{F_r,F_\theta,F_\phi}=
\pmatrix{F_x,F_y,F_z}
\begin{pmatrix}
\sin\theta\cos\phi&\cos\theta\cos\phi&-\sin\phi\\
\sin\theta\sin\phi&\cos\theta\sin\phi&\cos\phi\\
\cos\theta &-\sin\theta & 0
 \end{pmatrix}
\,.
$$
Points of $\mathbb R^3$ are transformed by
\begin{align}\tag4
x &= r \cos\phi\sin\theta\,, &y&=r\sin\phi\sin\theta\,,&z&=\cos\theta\,.
\end{align}
(I don't understand what your corresponding equations at the end mean).

I emphasize that these expressions are not the spherical components of $\boldsymbol{F}\,!$

Instead from (3), when $\pmatrix{F_x,F_y,F_z}=(x,y,z)$ as in your case, we get
the components of $\boldsymbol{F}$ as
\begin{align}\tag{as expected}
F_r&=r\sin^2\theta\cos^2\phi+r\sin^2\theta\sin^2\phi+r\cos^2\theta=r\,,\\[2mm]
F_\theta&=r\cos\theta\sin\theta\cos^2\phi+r\cos\theta\sin\theta\sin^2\phi-r\cos\theta\sin\theta=0\,,\\[2mm]
F_\phi&=-r\sin\theta\cos\phi\sin\phi+r\sin\theta\sin\phi\cos\phi=0\,.
\end{align}

The values $F_\theta=F_\phi=0$ are also expected since the field
$\boldsymbol{F}$ only points in the radial direction away from the origin.

The divergence in sperical coordinates is therefore
\begin{align}
\operatorname{div}\boldsymbol{F}&=\frac1{r^2}\frac{\partial(r^2F_r) }{\partial r}+\frac1{r\sin\theta}\frac{\partial(F_\theta\sin\theta)}{\partial\theta}
+\frac1{r\sin\theta}\frac{\partial F_\phi}{\partial\phi}\\[2mm]
&=\frac1{r^2}\frac{\partial r^3}{\partial r}=3\,.
\end{align}
